# Sorting lines with vim by lines chunk

Tags: sorting, vim, lines

Can I sort lines in vim depending on a part of line and not the complete line?
e.g

```
My Name is Deus Deceit
```

I would like to sort depending on the column that the name starts + 6 columns
for example 
sort by column 19-25 and vim will only check those characters for sorting.
If it can be done without a plugin that would be great. ty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out `:help :sort`. The command takes an options `{pattern}` whose matched text is skipped (i.e. sorting happens after the match.

For example, to sort by column 19+ (see `:help /\%c` and the related regexp atoms):

```
:sort /.*\%19c/
```

Comment: Ty for your answer but... I'm using vim for 2 days now. So what you just typed there, really doesn't make any sense to me... maybe I should just give up :S

Comment: Thanks for the help pointer! Perhaps `:sort r /\%19c.*\%25c/` is an improvement ?

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to just type a command that I have no clue how it works. Can you add explanation of what does what in that line pls? It would be really helpful and understanding it would make me able to do it again and again on various situations instead of coming back at the forum and typing the same question with different values. I know it's obvious which values I have to change for different circumstances, but I think you get my point. Ty

Comment: `r` means to sort by the regular expression pattern (inside `/` and `/`). The pattern matches everything between the 19th and the 25th column (i.e. 19th column is `\%19c`, and `.*` captures what's between those columns)

Comment: Yes that's understandable but still seems like I've got a lot to learn. TY

Comment: Can you tell me where i can find documentation for all those %19c or .* e.t.c?

Comment: `.*` is a regular expression, `.` matched any character and `*` means `zero or more ocurrences of the before`. A friend of mine just made a cool application, a RegExp game which you can google translate (we're from Brazil :)) http://games.vidageek.net/play/regex/task/0

Comment: After two days, custom sorting is a pretty advanced topic already :-) Protip: Learn how the built-in `:help` is organized, how you navigate it, and read read read. It's very useful and detailed; I have already included the pointers in my answer. And be patient with Vim; after 10+ years with Vim, I'm still learning new stuff every day...